# Access 2016 #Type! Errors When Changing Selection

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

On a form that I'm designing there are several textboxes whose displayed values are linked to the selection of a combobox via DLookup expressions in their control source properties:

```
=DLookUp("[fieldAcronym]","[myTable]","fieldName='" &[Forms]![myForm]![cboTest].[Text] & "'")
```

With this I am able to get my expected functionality when repeatedly changing the selection of the combobox, as the textbox values all change accordingly.

However, whenever I select an item displayed inside of any listbox that is also on the form, all of my above mentioned textboxes immediately begin to display the "#Type!" error message.

These listbox's items are also linked to the above combobox's selection via the following Row Source query:

```
SELECT myTable.Documents, myTable.fieldName
FROM myTable
WHERE (((myTable.fieldName)=[Forms]![myForm]![cboTest]));
```

---

Thanks in advance, I'm fairly new to access and I was unable to find a solution via the sophisticated SWE tool that is the Google Search Bar.

Comment: You cannot access the `Text` property, unless the control has the focus. Try using the `Value` property instead.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes that fixed it. Thank you so much. I had a feeling it was something simple.

Comment: DLookup can perform slowly with large dataset and this can sometimes be noticeable on form. It would be unnecessary if field is included in combobox RowSource. Then expression in textbox can reference combobox column by index, index begins with 0: `=[cboDoc].Column(2)`.

Comment: Another option is to include lookup table in form RecordSource, bind textbox to fieldAcronym field, set as Locked Yes and TabStop No to prevent edit.